# CSS3 animation not working when uploaded on the server

Tags: html, css

Following is a part of the css code for a website I'm working on.The .textbox:hover part works fine locally but not when I upload it on the server.

The textbox is a some text which animates and should pause on hover. The rest of the animation works fine but the hover part does not.
I first thought there is some browser incompatibility issue but it looks like it is something else since it works the same on all browsers.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
/* CSS for textbox */    

.textbox
{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
    position:relative;
    animation-name:myfirst;
    animation-duration:5s;
    animation-timing-function:linear;
    animation-delay:2s;
    animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    animation-direction:alternate;
    animation-play-state:running;
    -webkit-animation-name:myfirst;
    -webkit-animation-duration:5s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;
    -webkit-animation-delay:2s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -webkit-animation-direction:alternate;
    -webkit-animation-play-state:running;
}

.textbox:hover
{
    -webkit-animation-play-state:paused;
    animation-play-state:paused;    
}

@keyframes myfirst    {
    0% {background:48D1CC; left:0px; top:0px;}
   25% {background:yellow; left:200px; top:0px;}
   50% {background:blue; left:200px; top:200px;}
  100% {background:#DCDCDC; left:0px; top:0px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes myfirst { /* Safari and Chrome */
    0% {background:#DCDCDC; left:0px; top:0px;}
   25% {background:yellow; left:200px; top:0px;}
   50% {background:blue; left:200px; top:200px;}
  100% {background:#DCDCDC; left:0px; top:0px;}
}
```

Comment: Is there another stylesheet <link>, <style>, or @import on the server version? I didn't look at the code closely, but my first thought is another rule with greater specificity is overriding the :hover thing.

Comment: No there isn't. I read somewhere that adding a parameter href='style.css?parameter=1' in the link tag helps in updating the stylesheets. But that didn't work either.

Comment: The `?parameter=1` is just a cache-buster to make sure the old CSS isn't being cached in your browser or a proxy and delivered to you, it's not a magic 'make CSS work' flag. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Adam said above, there may be another resource being delivered in the server version. Check the page source, inspect the network calls in something like Firebug or Chrome Dev Tools to see what resources are actually being delivered. It could also be that your code isn't being delivered at all--is there a network error (404 or 500, e.g.) when you attempt to load the resource from the server?

Assuming it's actually being delivered to your browser and there are no other resources conflicting, what about the page itself? Is your page context and CSS selector chain the same in the local and remote versions? For example, if your server version assembles a page out of multiple components (e.g., header, sidebar, footer, content, widgets, etc), the assembly process may nest your component differently from how it appears locally when you load just the component, and your CSS selectors may be interacting differently.

Comment: This led me on the good path, but there was no such issue in my case, it was simply the CSS file being cached... I had to access specifically the CSS file on the server and add "?" to the url in order to refresh the cache, then it worked. Another simpler solution would be to simply clear up all browser history.